# Import Proc definition from network file with BULK

Tags: t-sql, bulk-load

I'm trying to create 1000+ Procs in MS SQL from supplied physical files as part of legacy migration located on Network . For now I plan to use sp with dynamic SQL to loop over all of them like in segment below, I had problem with BULK ROWTERMINATOR, so I just dummied it with bunch of ZZZZ, is there any other correct way to set it to NONE, so all string will be loaded into single row for run. I also use Nvarchar(Max) for my field.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #imp;
CREATE TABLE #imp (Col varchar(max))
BULK INSERT  #imp
FROM '//TFSNetwork/log/Install/sp_Test02.sql'
  WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '\nzzzzzzzzzZZZ')      ---<< ?????
select top 1 @Sql = Col from #imp
 EXEC (@sql);

----------------------------------------------------sp_Test02.sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Test]   
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT GETDATE() AS TS
END

-----------------------------------------------------------------

Load whole file into single row/column
```

Comment: `NVARCHAR(MAX)` can handle text with embedded row terminators (and you'll want them later on write, won't you?). Does providing the correct row terminators for your files generate an error?

Comment: Thanks Eric, you can test with default RT so you will get 8 rows for each line of code, as it seen in any Notepad app. In reality definition for sql object stored without  RTerminators, I think its' just matter of how test editor works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'` is what used by default ,that's why you get it once omitted at all. Don't think we can or will want to change this behavior rather use your Z combo).
Same thing can be done with another BULK , in this case no need any ROWTERM options.

```
declare @myFile varchar(max) 
select @myFile = BulkColumn
from openrowset(BULK '//Network/Path/Test02.sql', single_blob) x;
SELECT @myFile
```