# Update SP Definition reading from file and run dynamic SQL, deal with EOL

Tags: t-sql, bulk

Hi I need to create new definitions for SP having their source in external physical files (imported from other TFS site, have 1000+ of them). I thought I solved this problem on my first [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57630968/import-proc-definition-from-network-file-with-bulk/57633352#57633352).
But now I see another problem if you read my file into single line I got an error `'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.`  I need bring end of of line into my `@sql`
The only solution I see now read all lines into table with multiple rows and then concatenate them ? which is quite complex. Is there any way to deal with `\n'` in more compact way ?  The code below produce error. `GO` should be on separate line alone.  My global task to read 100+ files and run code inside.
And I don't have any access to that source DB they came from, just need to deal with flat files. Don't have any option to do Right Click on database, etc..

I think probably it's wrong way at all, I can bring those files into TFS/SQL project and do something out of TFS, probably should be be some way to apply new codes...(?)

```
CREATE TABLE #imp (Col varchar(max))
BULK INSERT  #imp
FROM '//TFSNetwork/log/Install/sp_Test02.sql'
  WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '\nzzzzz')      ---<< ?????
select top 1 @Sql = Col from #imp
 EXEC (@sql);

---  This is content of my sample file sp_Test02
USE MAGDA_Test
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
/*
Description:
*/
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Test]   
AS  
BEGIN  

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT GETDATE() AS TS
END

Actual result: Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Expected Result:  SP Created OK


--I suspect that SSMS/ doing some own stuff on line breaks, b'z this in this test we still have single line
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)   = 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.'
SELECT @sql  --- 1 line
Print  @sql  --- 2 lineS
```

Comment: Just tried to do `REPLACE(@sql,'GO','GO' + CHAR(10))`  to insert eol character, still doesn't work. Looks like I need to load all lines into separate rows and somehow stuff them .

Comment: Why would inserting `Char( 10 )` into `GolfScores` help? Be careful when doing "simple" substitutions across a large pool of code (or data).

Comment: Tx Habo, sorry not clear what you suggested, I tried all combos. it works only for PRINT, but not for SELECT or EXEC. SSMS replace those with space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Use `sqlcmd` you can compose multiple entries for all files in .bat file and run in single click. This way it works fine with all CR/LF. Just get enough permissions for your db.
Below is the contents of simple .bat file.Can use universal `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE` inside your .sql

```
 @echo off
sqlcmd -S dbServ10 -U UserAcct -P UserPsw -i "//TFSNetwork/log/Install/sp_Test01.sql"
 sqlcmd -S dbServ10 -U UserAcct -P UserPsw -i "//TFSNetwork/log/Install/sp_Test02.sql"
...
...
 sqlcmd -S dbServ10 -U UserAcct -P UserPsw -i "//TFSNetwork/log/Install/sp_Test100.sql"
```